# Filter Date for Reporting

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, navision

I am currently working with reports in Navision by a "book sales" currently use 2 variables "Date" one for the start and one for the end of the filter, but I wonder if you can only use a single variable where the user directly enter "month" and "year". Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

If you are setting the filter with SETRANGE you need two values. But if you use SETFILTER you can use a string with a date filter like this:

010115..103115

p1..p3

and the just:

DateField.SETFILTER(filterstring);

Answer (score 0):

Yes, when the user put the month and year data you by code transform this info in date values example:

**Variables from and to = date**

```
from := DMY2DATE(1, Month, Year);
EVALUATE(to, FORMAT(CALCDATE('+1M', Desde) -1));
YourTable.SETRANGE("Posting Date", from, to);
```